# should you be able to define a friend within a class?

Tags: c++

the following code compiles fine under gcc:

```
class vec3
{

private:

  float data[3];

public:

  vec3(float x, float y, float z)
  {
    data[0] = x;
    data[1] = y;
    data[2] = z;
  }

  void operator =(const vec3 &v)
  {
    data[0] = v.data[0];
    data[1] = v.data[1];
    data[2] = v.data[2];
  }

  friend vec3 operator *(float a, const vec3 &v)
  {
    vec3 res(v.data[0], v.data[1], v.data[2]);
    res.data[0] *= a;
    res.data[1] *= a;
    res.data[2] *= a;
    return res;
  }

};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  vec3 v(1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
  vec3 u = 2*v;
  return 0;
 }
```

it seems tho the operator * is defined within the class it is compiled as a non-member function because it is declared as friend. is this the standard behaviour? it seems a bit of an odd way to define a non-member function, I haven't seen this way of defining non-member friends in any text-books/faqs (normally declared within the class and defined outside).

james

Comment: Yes. I hate when people do that. It makes it hard to tell members from non members. I prefer defining the friend separately from the class (and it part of our coding standard). But it is legal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes..

According to the standard docs, `11.4 Friends - 6`

A function can be defined in a friend declaration of a class if and only if the class is a non-local class (9.8), **the function
name is unqualified**, and the function **has namespace scope**.

Example:

```
class M {
friend void f() { } // definition of global f, a friend of M,
// not the definition of a member function
};
```

Note that the function name is unqualified and it is a global function which has the scope of the associated namespace in where it is defined..

Answer (score 2):

It's standard and very useful.  Even if friendship isn't needed (i.e. only streaming public values), I often define inside some class "X":

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const X& x)
{
    return os << x.a << " & " << x.b;
}
```

In your example, the operator* needs to be a friend to access data, but needs to be a non-member as the lhs value is not an instance of the class.  Don't be confused by the fact it's defined - as distinct from only declared - inside the class.  That doesn't change anything except that the function is implicitly as if "inline" qualified (which is only a compiler hint and doesn't guarantee inlining), avoiding issues with the one-definition rule during multiple inclusions.

Comment: yes it is very useful, I'm just moving a load of methods from outside definitions to inside... this makes the code read a lot better and saves on a load of declarations in my class :)

Comment: @james edge: Is that sarcasm?

Answer (score 0):

It is standard behavior, and I've seen it at least once in Effective C++.